# Make result sheet in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table in mysql but no idea how to show result in my required format.

Marks (table)

```
ID     student_id      class_id     subject_id     obtained_marks       total_marks
1          1               1            11               68                  100     
2          2               1            11               63                  100     
3          3               1            11               61                  100     
4          1               1            12               45                  100     
5          2               1            12               75                  100     
6          3               1            12               61                  100     
7          1               1            13               42                  100     
8          2               1            13               84                  100     
9          3               1            13               78                  100
```

Where subject_id 11=English, 12=Math, 13=Science. And now I want to show result sheet like that

```
Student_id        English      Math      Science    
     1              68          63         61        
     2              45          75         84        
     3              61          61         78
```

Can anyone tell me how can I form this sort of query?

Comment: Try using `pivot ` operator

Answer (score 0):

Try `pivoting data like this`

```
Select * from table
    Pivot
    (
    Max (obtainedmarks)
    For studentid in ([english],[math],[science])
    )
    Group by studentid
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do pivot in mysql, though i havent tried your case pratically but sql below should work

```
 select 
    student_id,
    SUM(english) as english,
    SUM(math) as math,
    SUM(science) as science
    FROM (
    SELECT 
    student_id,
    CASE WHEN  subject_id = 11 THEN  obtained_marks else 0  end as English , 
    CASE WHEN  subject_id = 12 THEN  obtained_marks else 0  end as Math , 
    CASE WHEN  subject_id = 13 THEN  obtained_marks else 0  end as science 
    from marks
    )tmp
group by student_id
```

you can run a query like

```
select * from subjects
```

to create below sql dynamically

```
    CASE WHEN  subject_id = 11 THEN  obtained_marks else 0  end as English , 
    CASE WHEN  subject_id = 12 THEN  obtained_marks else 0  end as Math , 
    CASE WHEN  subject_id = 13 THEN  obtained_marks else 0  end as science
```

i.e

```
foreach($subject as $id=>$name){
  $sql.=CASE WHEN  subject_id = $id THEN  obtained_marks else 0  end as $name, 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select t.student_id,sum(t.english) as  English,sum(t.maths) as  Maths,
        sum(t.science) as Science from
     (select student_id,case when subject_id=11 then obtained_marks else 0 end as english,
       case when subject_id =12 then obtained_marks else 0 end as maths,
       case when subject_id =13 then obtained_marks else 0 end as science from Marks) as 
       t group by t.student_id
```

Answer (score -1):

You should change your table structure like this

```
ID     student_id      class_id     english_marks   Maths_marks  science_marks
1          1               1            11               68           55
```

Then you can fetch each row on its respect TABLE HEAD

```
 <table>
<th>Student_id</th>
<th>English</th>
<th>Math</th>
<th>Science<th>

while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo '<td>'.$fetch[student_id].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$fetch[english_marks].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$fetch[Maths_marks].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$fetch[science_marks].'</td>';

}

</table>
```

This is a good and easy way to do that :)

Comment: I have a separate table which has all subjects and i can call them through inner join query.